# Prevent a program adding itself to startup programs automatically

Tags: dropbox, startup-applications

I find my dropbox auto adds itself to startup programs, even after I unchecked it from the startup prefrences. However, when I manually started dropbox sometime, it automatically added itself to startup. Here is the experiment I did. (Ubuntu 14 LTS)

1. Uncheck dropbox from startup.
2. Exit dropbox
3. Manually start dropbox
4. Then dropbox is checked in the startup.

How to disable a program (e.g., dropbox) adding itself to startup programs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The startup preferences is stored at `~/.config/autostart/`. Take dropbox for example, it auto adds itself to startup by adding/editing the `~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` file. So a simple solution change that file and make it root-editable only.

1. vim ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop. Then change `Exec=dropbox start -i` to `Exec=`
2. chmod 600 ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop. This makes the file only accessible by its user.
3. sudo chown root:root ~/.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop. This changes the user of the file to root.

Answer (score -1):

Changing preferences to prevent dropbox changing login items is good.

Yet simpler is changing dropbox preferences and deselecting "Start dropbox on system startup".